# Creating new dictionary from old dictionary

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to create a new dictionary from an old one to get only the values I'll new in a df in the future. But the function I created is returning always the same key+values.

```
def load_data():

    with open('./data/awards.json', 'r') as file:
        json_file = json.load(file)        

    events_dict = {}

    for data_raw in json_file:
        events_dict['event'] = (data_raw['Event'])

        #form categories_list
        categories_list = []
        for all_data in data_raw['Data']:
            for awards_data in all_data['nomineesWidgetModel']['eventEditionSummary']['awards']:

                #check if it's a premium category
                if categories_data['isPremiumCategory'] == True:
                    for categories_data in awards_data['categories']:
                        categories = {}
                        categories['category_name'] = (categories_data['categoryName'])

                        #form nomination_list
                        nomination_list = []
                        for nominations_data in categories_data['nominations']:

                            primary_nominees = nominations_data['primaryNominees']
                            if len(primary_nominees)>0:
                                nominee1 = primary_nominees[0]['name']

                            secondary_nominees = nominations_data['secondaryNominees']
                            if len(secondary_nominees)>0:
                                nominee2 = secondary_nominees[0]['name']

                            nomination_list.append([nominee1, nominee2, nominations_data['isWinner']])

                        categories['nominations'] = nomination_list                    
                        categories_list.append(categories)
                    events_dict['categories'] = categories_list

    return events_dict
```

My intention is to get for each award the category, nominations an if it is a winner or not. What I'm getting now is 11 times the same event.

I've tried changing the indentation, append the dict to a list first but nothing helped... I'm sure it's something pretty basic, but I'm new to Python and not seeing my error.

[json file](https://gist.github.com/isafloriano/f468c631502435f5452ff6b545f79411)

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: can you add a snippet of your raw data?

Comment: `events_dict['event'] = (data_raw['Event'])` is going to overwrite at each iteration. You also need to swich around some logic here: `if categories_data['isPremiumCategory'] == True:` should come after `for categories_data in awards_data['categories']:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was a bit off. You want to initialise your `events_dict = {}` in your loop, then you can append that into a list, which I named `results`.

```
def load_data():

    with open('C:/test/awards.json', 'r') as file:
        json_file = json.load(file)        


    results = []  #<---- initialize result list
    for data_raw in json_file:
        events_dict = {} #<--- here initialize your dictionary then build it
        events_dict['event'] = data_raw['Event']

        #form categories_list
        categories_list = []
        for all_data in data_raw['Data']:
            for awards_data in all_data['nomineesWidgetModel']['eventEditionSummary']['awards']:

                #check if it's a premium category
                for categories_data in awards_data['categories']:    #<---- Need to switch this line
                    if categories_data['isPremiumCategory'] == True:  #<---This needs to follow your loop
                        categories = {}
                        categories['category_name'] = (categories_data['categoryName'])

                        #form nomination_list
                        nomination_list = []
                        for nominations_data in categories_data['nominations']:

                            primary_nominees = nominations_data['primaryNominees']
                            if len(primary_nominees)>0:
                                nominee1 = primary_nominees[0]['name']
                            else:
                                nominee1 = ''


                            secondary_nominees = nominations_data['secondaryNominees']
                            if len(secondary_nominees)>0:
                                nominee2 = secondary_nominees[0]['name']
                            else:
                                nominee2 = ''


                            nomination_list.append([nominee1, nominee2, nominations_data['isWinner']])

                        categories['nominations'] = nomination_list                    
                        categories_list.append(categories)
                        events_dict['categories'] = categories_list
            results.append(events_dict) #<---- once that dictionary is filled, you can append it into that result list, then move on to make a new events_dict with the next iteration

    return results
```